# Run Mongo on custom port in Docker and disable default port

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am working with docker image for mongo and I am able to successfully configure and deploy it. I want to change the port name and disable the default port name. I have tried multiple things like starting it on different port and mounting different configuration file. Its working on different port but its also working on default port (27017). I am trying to make it work only on the custom port and disable 27017. 
How can I do that?

Approaches tried

```
docker run --name insights-mongo -d -p 28001:27017 -v `pwd`/mongoData:/data/db insights/mongo
```

( This works but both 28001 & 27017  are available )

```
docker run --name insights-mongo -d -v `pwd`/mongoData:/data/db -v `pwd`/config/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf insights/mongo
```

(mongod.conf is not overriding the existing docker config and still running in default port 27017)

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 28001
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ that it's available on port 27017? How are you verifying this?

Comment: @VinceBowdren My connection string in my code works both with 27017 and 28001. And i can connect to both 28001 and 27017 of I use tool like robomongo

Comment: docker run --name insights-mongo -d -p 28001:27017 -v `pwd`/mongoData:/data/db insights/mongo

is the correct approach. Not sure why it didnt work earlier. Thanks for your time